# Unable to delete dashboard or edit with json.

Tags: json, dashboard, einstein-analytics

Appending /json to the dashboard URL previously brought me to an editor so that I could fix the json, however, now it doesn't do that. I'm unable to delete or edit this dashboard. Any ideas?

[image: Application Error]

Comment: Did you try this?
To access Expert Editor Mode, open the lens or dashboard you want to edit, and press CTRL+E for PCs or CMD+E for Macs.

Comment: I'm unable to open the dashboard. The screenshot I posted is what appears when I try to open the dashboard.

Comment: did you trying appending /insights/web/lens.apexp to your instance?
in your case try opening this
**https://na35.salesforce.com/insights/web/lens.apexp**

Comment: also the screenshot is not when you open the dashboard. You have appended /json to get into editor mode.

Comment: You are correct Sarath. To be more specific, I get the identical "Application Error" dialog when I attempt to open or edit the dashboard. Also, thanks for the lens apex URL tip.

Answer (score 1):

After a crash course in using curl, I was able to issue a delete command via curl to remove the corrupted dashboards that I couldn't open or delete through salesforce GUI. Here are the key commands I used, in case someone else runs across this:

```
curl -X DELETE https://na35.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/analytics/dashboards/<your unique dashboard ID> -H "Authorization: Bearer <your 112 alphanumeric salesforce sessionID>"
```

And here's how to get your salesforce sessionID from the Developer Console (execute anonymous).

```
SYSTEM.DEBUG('Session Id : ' +Userinfo.getSessionId());
```

Your unique dashboard ID is the final 18 characters in your URL when you attempt to access your corrupted dashboard. If you're on a salesforce server different than na35, you will also have to change the curl URL 'na35' to whatever server you're on. I'm guessing there is an easier way to do this, but I wasn't able to find it.